# how to execute a CMD command from the output of another command

Tags: cmd

In Windows Command Prompt (CMD), when my command1 is executed, the output is a full command (command2) with arguments.
My question is, is there a way to execute command2 directly just after command1 is executed?
Usually the commands could be piped like "command1 | command2". but here even the command name of command2 is a part of the output of command1. So I'm not sure if there's a way to use the pipe.

Comment: Redirect to a .cmd file. Then run the .cmd script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question is that command1's *text output* is another command name - command2. If so, there's a way though not so clean. Try

```
> for /F "tokens=*" %a in ('first command') do %a additionalSecondCommandArg
```

Example. My win-10 has notepad.exe in \Windows. If I want to open aaa.txt with it,

```
> for /F "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /B \windows\note*.exe') do %a aaa.txt
```

which runs notepad.exe and trys to open aaa.txt. You can check what "tokens=*" means by typing "for /?" in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

An example for usage:
going to (`CD /d`) location of a file:
(I named it `cdwhere.cmd`)

```
@echo off
set param=where %1
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('%param%') do cd /d %%~dpa
set param=
```

example of usage :

```
>cdwhere explorer
output:
>C:\Windows>_
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. It shows the output of a command. Requested was to execute the output